# PyInstaller: "No such file or directory"

Tags: pyinstaller

I recently compiled a Python 3 file using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). When I tried to run

```
./main
```

it said the following message:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygame/pkgdata.py", line 67, in getResource
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEIkMQ7na/pygame/freesansbold.ttf'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I do use the [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) module.

Comment: It should be packed [automatically](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_py/__pyinstaller/hook-pygame.py#L28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data="<PATH_OF_FILE_IN_YOUR_ENV>/pygame/freesansbold.ttf;/pygame/freesansbold.ttf" main.py
```

Basically you need to find freesansbold.ttf from your virtual environment and explicitly add it inside the bundle.